# AngularJS JSONP not updating key value to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I was trying to update the `channel.status` object with the `//Second JSONP` callback function.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    channels = [];
    channel = {};

    followersAPI = followersAPI.replace(/theUser/, user);
    followersAPI = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(followersAPI);

    // First JSONP
    $http.jsonp(followersAPI).then(function (response) {
        var follows = response.data.follows;

        for (var i = 0; i < follows.length; i ++) {
            var currentChannel = follows[i].channel;

            if (currentChannel.status == null) {
                currentChannel.status = "offline";
            }

            channel = {
                name: currentChannel.name,
                display_name: currentChannel.display_name,
                logo: currentChannel.logo,
                url: currentChannel.url,
                status: "loading"
            };

            streamAPI = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/";
            streamAPI += channel.name;
            streamAPI = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(streamAPI);

            // Second JSONP
            $http.jsonp(streamAPI).then(function (response) {
                data = response.data;
                if (data.stream == null) {
                    channel["status"] = "offline";
                } else {
                    channel["status"] = data.stream.channel.status;
                }
            });
            channels.push(channel);
        }
    });
    $scope.channels = channels;
    console.log($scope.channels);
});
```

There's no error message, but only the last `channel{}` object in `channels[]` array was updated.

[image: jsonp output]

Here's the HTML part for `channel.status`:

```
 <div id="channel-status" class="col-md-6">
        <a
        class="btn"
        href="{{channel.url}}"
        target="_blank">
            {{channel.status}}
        </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For asynchronous call `$http.jsonp` in `for-loop`, in its callback you will only get instance of last defined `channel`.as a solution, you should move all things about `channel` into the `Second JSONP`.

```
var currentChannel = follows[i].channel;

streamAPI = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/";
streamAPI += channel.name;
streamAPI = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(streamAPI);

// Second JSONP
$http.jsonp(streamAPI).then(function (response) {
    data = response.data;
    if (currentChannel.status == null) {
        currentChannel.status = "offline";
    }

    channel = {
        name: currentChannel.name,
        display_name: currentChannel.display_name,
        logo: currentChannel.logo,
        url: currentChannel.url,
        status: "loading"
    };

    if (data.stream == null) {
        channel["status"] = "offline";
    } else {
        channel["status"] = data.stream.channel.status;
    }
    channels.push(channel);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that before, and it caused some other problem: if I push `channels.push(channel);` into the `// Second JSONP`, all the other properties in `channel{}` duplicated except for `$$hashKey`; if it's outside (and inside the `for loop`), it shows `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed.`.

Comment: @hanabinoir you can add `track by $index` to avoid that error.

Comment: it comes out with no error message, but the properties still duplicate. maybe it is not good to use the callback in `jsonp` in a `for-loop`.

Comment: @hanabinoir It will be duplicate if  `Second JSONP` have duplicate results. `track by $index` will let `ng-repeat` to ignore duplicates but shows all the records.

Comment: As you said, the `jsonp` callback is only taking the last definition from the for loop, and duplicates it. I'm looking for a better structure than this with `jsonp` inside the `for-loop`.